# How to install RMagick gem in Ruby 1.8.6 MingW?

Tags: windows, ruby, mingw, rmagick

Do you have a detailed guide for this? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Windows:

```
gem install rmagick --source http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/61207/rmagick-2.11.0.gem
```

but according to this [Installation Faq](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html) you need to install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) first

you might also want to consult [Seamless Support for MinGW](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=26150&group_id=12&atid=135) and [open-discussion](http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=25134&forum_id=32) and the [notes of Akita on Rails](http://akitaonrails.com/2009/1/13/the-best-environment-for-rails-on-windows)  on the [One-Click Ruby Installer](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/47082/ruby186-27_rc2.exe) by [Luis Lavena](http://blog.mmediasys.com/)

**UPDATE**: here's an update on [Akita on Rails' article](http://akitaonrails.com/2009/04/27/the-best-environment-for-rails-on-windows-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=21495&group_id=12&atid=134
also looks hopeful

Comment: http://betterlogic.com/roger/?p=2186
is how to "really" compile it using mingw :)